# Javascript Inheritance: One Subclass gets the Prototype, the other doesn't

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype

I have a `SuperClass` "class", and this class is to be inherited (via the prototype chain) by `SubClassA` and `SubClassB`. However, while the inheritance appears to work for `SubClassA`, it fails for `SubClassB`. The code is below:

```
function SuperClass(childCell){
    this.childCell = childCell;
    this.children = new Array(9);
    for(i=0; i<9; i++) {
        this.children[i] = new this.childCell();
    }
}
function SubClassA(){
    this.num = 1;
}
SubClassA.prototype = new SuperClass(SubClassB);
function SubClassB(){
    this.num = 2;
}
SubClassB.prototype = new SuperClass(SubClassC);
function SubClassC(){
    this.num = 3;
}
var x = new SubClassA();
```

In this code, I set `x` to an object of `SubClassA`, and this should in turn give me a `children` property containing 9 `SubClassB` objects. It does this properly, but in turn, each `SubClassB` object should contain 9 `SubClassC` objects. However, after inspecting the console, I found that none of the `SubClassB` objects actually contain the `childCell` or the `children` properties that it *was* supposed to inherit via prototype.

In other words, `x.children[0]` returned `SubClassB {num: 2}`, and had none of the other properties.

Why does the inheritance work for `SubClassA` but not `SubClassB`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try reorder your declaration sample like

```
function Parent(childCell){
    this.childCell = childCell;
    this.children = new Array(9);
    for(var i=0; i<9; i++) {
        this.children[i] = new this.childCell();
    }
}
function ChildA(){
    this.num = 1;
}
function ChildB(){
    this.num = 2;
}
function ChildC(){
    this.num = 3;
}

ChildB.prototype = new Parent(ChildC);
ChildA.prototype = new Parent(ChildB);
```

your problem - you call `ChildB` constructor before you add prototype to it

**UPDATE**

@Bagavatu when you create object you use prototype which set for constructor function, then you can change prototype properties and this changes will be apply to all objects with this prototype.
In your case you change reference to prototype so it does not apply to object which was created before. You can test it in simple example

```
function A() {this.cell = 10}
function B() {this.num =1}

var b1 = new B(); // b1 = {num:1}

B.prototype = new A();
var b2 = new B(); // b1 = {num:1}, b2 = {num:1, cell:10}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. Could you explain a little more about why I would have to define the ChildB prototype first though?

Comment: @Bagavatu try see my updated answer, i hope it is now more clear

Answer (score -1):

I usually dont dig that much deep.But when we use sub classing in javascript,folllow the following pattern.

```
function Superclass() { }
Superclass.prototype.someFunc = function() { };

function Subclass() { }
Subclass.prototype = new Superclass();
Subclass.prototype.anotherFunc = function() { };

var obj = new Subclass();
```

Comment: Hmmm...how would this help in my case though? I do believe I have what is written here.